# Equivalent of the $[*] jsonpath for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jsonpath, json-value

I would like to use a JSON path like `$[*].name` or `$[..].name` on a JSON like this one:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "John"}, 
    {"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}, 
    {"id": 3, "name": "Peter"}
]
```

To get as result:

```
["John", "Mary", "Peter"]
```

But when I try this on [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/8qAsXANP) **2019** using:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json_data, '$[*].name')
FROM users
```

I got this error:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '*' is found
> at position 2.

So how can I get the expected result using a `jsonpath` compatible with SQL Server?

Comment: Well, by itself, `["John", "Mary", "Peter"]` isn't valid JSON, so if that's the result you're actually wanting to might want to use other SQL Server functionality like `STRING_AGG` instead.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: There is a link to fiddle with ddl

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Perfectly valid to have a bare array, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, json_data NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (json_data) VALUES 
('[{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Peter"}]'),
('[{"id": 1, "name": "Sunny"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Paul"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Michael"}]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, result = '[' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.name'),CHAR(34)), ',') + ']'
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_data, '$') AS j
GROUP BY ID;
```

**Output**

| ID | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["John","Mary","Peter"] |
| 2 | ["Sunny","Paul","Michael"] |

Comment: But how can I do that with all lines of users table?

Comment: Please see my comment under your question.

Comment: Thanks, the DDL with the create table is avaliable in the question as a link

Comment: `STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.name'), 'json') + '"', ',')` also could just do `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_data) WITH (name nvarchar(100)) AS j` and `STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(j.name, 'json') + '"', ',')`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat clearer and more accurate method

- Use a schema for `OPENJSON` to immediately parse out properties into columns.
- Use `STRING_ESCAPE` rather than `QUOTENAME` for correct quoting.

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, json_data NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (json_data) VALUES 
('[{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Mary"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Peter"}]'),
('[{"id": 1, "name": "Sunny"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Paul"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Michael"}]');

SELECT
  ID,
  result = '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(j.name, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_data)
  WITH (
    name nvarchar(100)
  ) AS j
GROUP BY ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/o2XDME-B)

Comment: error: Must declare the table variable "@tbl".

Comment: Sorry thought it was obvious @tbl would be your table name

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on? If it's 2016 then you can't use `STRING_AGG`, you need to aggergate using `FOR XML` or similar

Comment: SQL SERVER 2019

Comment: Works fine on 2019 as far as I can see https://dbfiddle.uk/ktnPPBmu